# Public shared preferences causes app to crash

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need to have a shared preference that can be accessed by multiple methods in my class. To do this I set the shared preference public like this:

```
public SharedPreferences myPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Then I can access it like this from two different methods:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myPreference.edit();
```

when I do this the app crashes, here is the logcat:

> 01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   Process: com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp, PID: 20873 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp.sundayActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference 01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method) 01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt
>   to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
>   android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
>   reference 01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:106)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp.sundayActivity.(sundayActivity.java:61)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439) 
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)  01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348) 
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)  01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
>   Method)  01-23 18:02:51.764
>   20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  01-23
>   18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
>   01-23 18:02:51.764 20873-20873/com.example.griffin.dinnerplannerapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException at getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035121/nullpointerexception-at-getdefaultsharedpreferences)

Answer (score 3):

You can't call `getApplicationContext()` before the `onCreate()` method is called, that may be why it's returning null and giving you this error.

Thus, I suggest you set the field in the `onCreate()`, or better yet just use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())` directly wherever you need to use the `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared permissions to Access external storage in you Manifest?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Edit 1:
Searched in the LogCat for a Detail found this

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()

take a look here [Get application context returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994612/get-application-context-returns-null) Maybe this helps.

Edit 2:
I add the main parts of the link:

You should create a static Context instance in `onCreate()` and make sure that you declare the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The Code for the context instance:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
```

//private static MyApp instance;
 private static Context mContext;

```
public static MyApp getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public static Context getContext() {
  //  return instance.getApplicationContext();
  return mContext;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
//  instance = this;
 mContext = getApplicationContext();    
}
```

}

And the Manifest:

`<application android:name="com.mypackage.MyApp">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</application>`

Comment: i was not able to comment in case of to low Reputation, sorry for that.