# Shared Preferences causes app to crash. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, main-activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, page1_user_notes.communicate{

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    //checkbox array list
    public ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    //user titleText Array List
    public ArrayList<String> titleTextArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    //user notesArrayList
    public ArrayList<String> notesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
    String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
   // PopupMenu popup
    LinearLayout ll;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp;
    PopupMenu popup;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    private int checkboxPopupCheck;

    String checkTitle;
    String checkNotes;

    //We will use this to store our shared preferences.
    public static final String SAVE = "MyPrefs";
    private EditText mTitle;
    private EditText mNotes;
    private String mTitleString = "titles";
    private String mNotesString = "notes";
    String t;
    String n;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // recovering the instance state
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        /***-----------Added after----------*/
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

//Shared preferences
        mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mNotes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        t = mTitle.getText().toString();
        n = mNotes.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SAVE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(mTitleString,t);
        editor.putString(mNotesString,n);
        editor.apply();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onCreate called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Here is my Main Activity class.

I have looked at

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

[Public shared preferences causes app to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970100/public-shared-preferences-causes-app-to-crash)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Log cat error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

 at com.myApps.Notes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
```

Line 103 is

```
t = mTitle.getText().toString();
```

So its a null pointer exception. To me that means the EditText hasn't been initialized yet.

Not sure what to try from here. Feel like I'm just throwing code around now...

Comment: It would seem that the `<EditText>` with ID `editText` is not in the `activity_main` layout, either directly, or in an `<include>`d layout. `findViewById(R.id.editText)` will return null in that case.

Comment: Right its not in the same layout. Its part of a fragment. So when I tried to use this in code in the onCreate() method in the fragment. The same thing happens.

Comment: A `Fragment`'s `View`s won't be available yet in its `onCreate()` method, since that runs before the `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: Ok. maybe I will try to make a method in the fragment. onCreateView() ...https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Actually that is what I tried. already. But ill give it a shot again.

Comment: You should already have an `onCreateView()` override in your `Fragment`, otherwise that will eventually cause a crash, too.

Comment: Yes I have that in the fragment. The fragment is working fine.

Comment: Whenever I try to initialize the `String t`  the app crashes

Comment: Ah--- so in the fragment you have to have `mTitle = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText);` I thought it was `getActivity().findViewById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
mTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
mNotes = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
t = mTitle.getText().toString();
n = mNotes.getText().toString();
```

The method `findViewById` returns the view only if a view with provided id exists in the activity, not in the fragments. Otherwise it will return null.

If the views are inside the fragment, you should get those views from inside the `onCreateView` method of your fragment.

```
mNotes = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```